# How to generate a set of strings and multiply each strings with another in jquery

Tags: jquery

say i have the following strings:

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 7
```

and i have two textbox:
code
code value

the question is, how do i generate unique strings with (a,b,c), and add them to the textbox 'code' and multiply each string with each other and add them to the textbox 'code value'

for example let say i generated:

```
"cba"
```

then multiply each value with each other like this:

```
7 * 6 * 5 = 210.
```

that is, the 'code' textbox will be equals to "cba"
and the 'code value' textbox will be equals to "210".
how can i achieve this?``

Comment: Please elaborate on where "a", "b", and "c" are coming from.  Are they variables?  Or page element?

Answer (score 1):

Set it up with an object so you can define the value of every letter if need be. Then try looping through each letter and grab their numerical value to multiply by. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b91ztd1e/1/)

```
var o = { // Define Letter Values
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6,
    g: 7,
    h: 8,
    i: 9,
    j: 10,
    k: 11,
    l: 12,
    m: 13,
    n: 14,
    o: 15,
    p: 16,
    q: 17,
    r: 18,
    s: 19,
    t: 20,
    u: 21,
    v: 22,
    w: 23,
    x: 24,
    y: 25,
    z: 26
};

$('input').on('keyup', function(){ // Set whatever event you want to trigger the function
    var str = $(this).val();        // Grab the string value
    var arr = str.split('');        // Split the string on every letter into an array
    var total = 0;
    $.each(arr, function(i, v){     // Loop through the letters
        var letterIndex = o[v];     // Get the numerical value of the current letter
        if(i === 0){                // If this is the first letter set the starting letter value
            total = letterIndex;
        } else {                    // Else multiply the current total by the letter's value
            total = total * letterIndex;
        }
    });
    $('#yourOtherTextarea').val(total);           // Do whatever you want with the results
});
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks alot, it worked like magic....one more thing, how would i display the result as i type in another textbox

Comment: I believe you can change the event from  'change' to 'keyup', then add another textarea, and instead of .html() on the div, run .val(total) on the new textarea.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer! thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your variables will always be one letter long, you can do

```
if(code.length){
    var result = eval(code[0]);
    for(var i = 1; i < code.length; i++){
        var temp = eval(eval('code[i]'));
        result = eval('temp*result');
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

See it in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/xgod258u/2/)